# Custom extraction rule in VS2008 doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, webtest

I'm creating a Web Test in VS2008 and have extended ExtractionRule. Now when I run test where my extraction rule used it displays "Request failed: Could not load type 'TypeName, version, locale etc'. This happens even though I added my class in designer.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. One **MUST** add his extraction rules to project **OTHER** than his WebTests project. I tend to create WebTests.Helpers project for that. Afterwards one must reference that project and compile it to use custom extraction rules.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:  another option (if you don't want to add a 2nd project) is to explicitly add your project's dll file to the Deployment section in the TestSettings.